# Tape or corner bead where Hardi meets Drywall?

Tags: drywall, tile, shower, cement-board, corner-bead

I need to finish the outside corner above the shower alcove. The shower ceiling is hardibacker and the wall outside the shower is drywall. Where these two meet, what is the proper way to finish it so it's a nice corner? I will just end up painting it.

The walls were easier because I had tile wrapping around the corner so I just taped and thinset those and tiled overtop. Not sure what to do for the ceiling since there won't be any tile.

[image: upper corner of shower alcove]

[image: close up of ceiling corner]

Comment: Can you take a picture?  These are usually pretty specific to the surroundings.

Comment: @DMoore pics added

Comment: I have vinyl corner bead but I'm not sure how to properly attach it to hardi

Comment: Normally I would have put in a metal corner trim but needs to go behind the tile.  Are you going to tile above the current tile and ceiling.  If so I would talk to tile company and ask if they have edging in this style.  That would by far be the easiest/best looking way of doing it.

Comment: I have one more finishing tile piece to put over the top layer of tile. I will not be tiling the ceiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar situation where the backer board extended a few inches past my planned tiling edge in my shower. After I had finished with the tile, I taped the joint and applied joint compound over the backer board and it seems great. It's been three years and there is no cracking or any problem with it. That's not exactly an answer but I hope it helps you decide.

Comment: That's essentially what I want to do but since it's an outside corner, I feel like I need to use some sort of corner bead so it looks proper. I wonder if I can just slap some thinset on the corner and stick the vinyl corner bead to it?

Comment: I ended up thin setting corner bead and then making it pretty with joint compound. I did this before putting the last row of tile up which made it pretty simple.

Comment: Tip: I wish I would have put RedGuard on the ceiling as well although I'm not sure if it would help with some of my staining issues from the water that accumulates up there

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would get something like the picture below to cover the side of the tile.  But it generally has to be installed under tile.  (you could still try it out and mud/caulk on the flat end but I don't see it lasting long looking good in a damp area)

[image]

Now you will have to go with some kind of bullnose or trim piece, much like you would trim out a door.  A chairrail, bullnose, double bullnose could all look good here.   From what I can see one of these would probably be the easiest way out of this now.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding my question. The tile edges will be finished with bullnose/chair rail. What I'm specifically asking for in this case is how to finish the top outside corner where drywall meets CBU (the area where there isn't any tile). Maybe I'm over thinking this and I can just use a corner bead with thinset and move on?